# Is a semimartingale that is continuous a continuous semimartingale?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ be a centered semimartingale that has continuous sample paths almost surely. Is it then true that $X$ is a continuous semimartingale? Meaning that $X$ has a decomposition $X=M+V$ where $M$ is a continuous local martingale and $V$ is a continuous finite variation process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer - the answer is yes. Rogers and Williams page 358.

Comment: What is the answer if you don’t mind me asking!

Comment: Please at least give a yes/no in the answer. Even better, you should make the answer self-contained, without relying on textbooks or contents behind paywalls etc.

Comment: @NateRiver the answer is yes.